# mule data mapper with file attachment and smtp

Tags: mule

My requirement is get the data from db, convert to csv format, send an email with the complete data of csv attachment.

My mule batch flows are given below.

```
<batch:job name="status-csv-smtp">
<batch:input>
    <db:select config-ref="Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select account_name , account_action ,employeed_id ,paytype_id , client_id , int_status , error_msg , logged_at from sfdc_status]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:select>
</batch:input>
<batch:process-records>
    <batch:step name="Batch_Step">
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>            
        <batch:commit size="200" doc:name="Batch Commit">
            <data-mapper:transform config-ref="JSON_To_CSV" doc:name="JSON To CSV"/>
        </batch:commit>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step name="Batch_Step1">
        <set-attachment attachmentName="status.csv" value="#[payload]" contentType="text/html" doc:name="SFDC Status"/>
        <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${smtp.host}" port="${smtp.port}" connector-ref="SMTP" to="${smtp.to}" from="${smtp.from}"  subject="Upload status" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>
    </batch:step>
</batch:process-records>
<batch:on-complete>
    <logger message="#[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</batch:on-complete>
```

Problem here is
1) if 100 records, 100 mails are triggering with empty data in file
2) If i move smtp and attachment to on complete, I am not able to get the csv file as an attachment
3) How do i pass payload data from step to on complete? recordVars did not work.

**EDIT**

I had database mapping issue, after selecting option in DataMapper as  Re-create Meta Data from output was able to get correct data. Removed object to json transformer now. [image: mapper]

I am following [link](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Database+Connector+Examples) and below reply from @Tyrone Villaluna. I am getting multiple email based on batch commit size(30) , how do I get the email with single attachment for entire records? It sends multiple email now and if the commit size is more than the records(say 200), then email doesn't trigger due to commit size. I am not sure about the no of records exists in the db.

[image: batch]

```
<batch:job name="status-csv-smtp">
<batch:input>
    <db:select config-ref="PSI_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select account_name , account_action ,employeed_id ,paytype_id , client_id , int_status , error_msg , logged_at from sfdc_status]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:select>
</batch:input>
<batch:process-records>
    <batch:step name="Batch_Step">
        <batch:commit size="30" doc:name="Batch Commit">
            <data-mapper:transform config-ref="List_Map__To_CSV_1List_Map__To_CSV_2" doc:name="List&lt;Map&gt; To CSV"/>
        <set-attachment attachmentName="status.csv" value="#[message.payload]" contentType="text/html" doc:name="SFDC Status"/>
        <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${smtp.host}" port="${smtp.port}" connector-ref="SMTP" to="${smtp.to}" from="${smtp.from}"  subject="Upload status" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>
        </batch:commit>
    </batch:step>
</batch:process-records>
<batch:on-complete>         
    <logger message="#[payload.processedRecords],[payload.failedRecords] #[payload.elapsedTimeInMillis]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</batch:on-complete>
```

Comment: For 100 records( since commitSize is 200), how may csv files are getting. is it '100' or '1'?.

Comment: @star, i made it to 30. If the record is less than 10, it won't commit at the end of process?

Comment: Thats is what I'm checking with you. Is it processing ? or waiting for next 20?

Comment: I retested it. table had 73 records, but commit I had specified 200. File generated at the end of process as a single file with 73 records.

Comment: cool great! I have given answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have you tried moving all components of Batch_Step1 into Batch Commit of Batch_Step? I think Batch Commit is clearing the records after (though not particularly sure)
2. Yes, record data (including flow variables) are indeed not available on batch complete. You will only see summary here. Hopefully will be available on future releases.
3. You could try a dirty approach. On batch step, store your data on a cache (use message rootId as key) or a static variable, then fetch it back on complete.

Comment: That is odd. The batch commit should still invoke even if the total records are less than its commit size. I have tried that and it works for me. Try debugging.. If really not working, just put all of those in batch step to input phase, your batch is not really doing anything per record anyway.

Comment: It is simple, Double click DataMapper and  near to eye symbol(Hide UnrelatedElement), you could see `open Properties`. Click on it and enabled header ( By default, header properties are in disabled state). If you need, require to enable manually.

Comment: Try as star suggested